# how come my image won't show up on my page?

Tags: html

very new to HTML coding! my image won't show up on my website. I've tried multiple paths and made sure spelling and quotes are all being used correctly.

here is my code I am trying to use:

```
<a href="http://shopkathleen.net"><img src="picture.jpg" ></a>
```

the index and picture are both in the same folder, so I don't think it's my path. I have tried creating a separate folder titled "img" and also tried the code:

```
<img src="img/picture.jpg" ></a>
```

again, all spelling is correct on files, I am frustrated as to why my page can't find the path for the photo.

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser's developer tools and refresh. Look for the request for your image and make sure it's not returning a 404 or some other error code.

Comment: Make sure your image name and extension are right. At default, the extensions are hidden in some OS. Your image name might be `picture.jpg.gif`.